# youtube-dl Chocolatey package

Tags: chocolatey, youtube-dl

[youtube-dl on Chocolatey packages](https://chocolatey.org/packages/youtube-dl)

When running `youtube-dl --version` command the output is `2016.06.16`. The latest [youtube-dl version](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/releases) at the moment is `2017.01.05`. At first I thought that the package maintainer has accidentally uploaded an outdated version, but the problem persists after several repository updates.

Comment: You should manually use the `upgrade` command (i.e. choco upgrade youtube-dl) and point it to the correct repository.

Comment: @Ramhound: I've done that, `youtube-dl v2017.01.05 is the latest version available based on your source(s)`

Comment: You also have to change the repository to one with the current version...Your currently pointed to a repository source that hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just done a fresh install of youtube-dl on a fresh Windows 7 machine, and I can confirm that it is working as expected.  The output of `youtube-dl --version` outputs `2017.01.05`.  I would suggest that you do the following...

Run `choco source` and verify that you get, at least, the following output:

> chocolatey - https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/ | Priority 0.

If you do, run the following:

> choco upgrade youtube-dl --force

To force the re-installation of the package.

If this still doesn't work, then run the following (at a PowerShell command window):

> &where.exe youtube-dl

To ensure that the you are running the version that chocolatey has installed.

Answer (score 0):

The program is up to date, I had a leftover file from an earlier install on my computer.